# Is there a way to have a function where given some arguments, it returns state and/or actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am currently building a simple web element editor with React using Redux. It works as it should work with a small number of elements. I can see though that when the number of elements gets on a two digit scale, it will be frustrating to organize and maintain. The reason is because I have to pass [IDs and names (local to the function data), State, Actions] to the function I call which in turn filters the arguments and calls other functions with the right arguments etc. I think it is more ifs than it is needed. Can it be done with a function where I can have all the state and the actions, pass it some arguments, choose the correct path and done?

I do not think that providing code will help with this question, you would have see my file system as well to have the whole picture.

I am a junior developer so please forgive me if this is a stupid question or similar. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll need to show some contextual code to make this question more specific, even if it is hypothetical.

Comment: I don't think I'm the only one who has no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I cannot find a way to describe it better at the moment. I am  trying to modify some other functions now and i will get to this later this weekend. I will post if i find a solution that works for me or if i can explain the whole idea better. Thank you for your time!